# Java applets launched using deployJava.js not working for Opera/Chrome on Mac?

Tags: java, macos, applet, google-chrome, opera

I noticed that the launching of Java applets using deployJava.js seems to have stopped working on some Mac browsers.  Safari and FF still work, but Opera and Chrome send the user to Java installation page, as if the plugin was not found.

Take for example [this](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/deployment/webstart/examples/dist/webstart_ComponentArch_DynamicTreeDemo/JavaWebStartAppPage.html).  If you click the launch button in Opera, it sends you to a Java installation page.  Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: I've found `deploy.js` isn't great, see a thread I started when facing similar problems http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1028900/what-is-the-rolls-royce-way-to-deploy-a-java-applet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up checking User-Agent HTTP header for "Opera" and in this case using standard  tag. For any other browser I use deploy deployJava.js as currently served by Sun.
I know that there are modified versions of deployJava.js (e.g. [this one](http://jira.atlassian.com/includes/deployJava.js) used by Atlassian JIRA) which correctly start the applet in Opera instead of sending the user to Java installation page. But in my case, this approach caused ClassLoader issues (truncated classes) with Opera as I was using applets packaged into several jar files (main + 3rd party jars).  had no such problems, even with Opera (which has buggy Java support as Sun claims).

Strangely, I had no issues with standard deployJava.js with Chrome (checked on Linux and Mac Snow Leopard).

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, could you offer a plain link to the `.jnlp`?

From the ["Deploying a Java Web Start Application"](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/deployment/webstart/deploying.html), "If you are not sure whether your end users will have the JavaScript interpreter enabled in their browsers, you can deploy the Java Web Start application directly by creating a link to the JNLP file..."